# Shoretel SDK C# - Call Recordings

Tags: c#, shoretel

My company is using ShoreTel's SDK to record inbound and outbound calling.  We are using LineRecord to handle the recording; however, it is storing the recordings on both the phone server and in the users voice mail.  The documentation says there is a way to prevent it from recording in both but doesn't say exactly how.

The code I am using for the LineRecord is:

```
m_STMLCtl.LineRecord(nLineID, nCallID, RoutePoint, m_STMLCtl.LineGetAddress(nLineID));
```

The ShoreTel STMLBrowser test application has this code:

```
STMLCtl.LineRecord(nLineToRecordFrom, nCallID, strExtensionToCall, strContext);
```

How do I prevent the voice recording from recording to the user's voice mail?

Comment: Seeing that there are only 6 questions tagged with `shortel` on SO, I'm not sure you're going to fine an answer for that here.  In cases like this, it's probably better just to go to the actual owners/developers of the API, and ask them yourself.

Comment: @George: Probably correct, but I just happened to look at the questions page at just the right time. :)

Comment: @DarkFalcon I stand corrected. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recording function just initiates a call to the specified extension. Whatever answers that call is responsible for recording the audio. If your recording is winding up in voice mail, then somehow the call is getting to the voice mail extension. If the call hits voice mail, then the recording will be saved in the mailbox of the extension specified in `strContext`. The only other option is to send the call to a route point and record the audio yourself.

As a note, the better place to ask for help is the [ShoreTel Developer Network group](http://groups.google.com/group/shoreteldevelopernetwork?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm going to try it out and not pass anything to the strContext and see if that will prevent the recording from showing up in the users' voice mail.

Comment: It will not. The only place ShoreTel can record natively is a mailbox. If you don't provide one, it will use the user's.